# Can't see last item in Listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone, listboxitem

I'm using the ReorderListBox (https://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/) in my windows phone application. I've got a Wrapped Text in my ListItems. Unfortunately, when the text of my Item is too long (like >300 characters), I can't use the reorder-button of my listboxitem, because I can't scroll down to see the full item/text.

```
<rlb:ReorderListBox VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" Name="Artikelliste" ItemsSource="{Binding Articlelist.Liste, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="30"
            Text="{Binding Bezeichnung}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
</rlb:ReorderListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set a height for your listbox

Comment: @Meee Gonna try it. But I think it's the wrong approach, because if I have a smaller phone and the height of my ListBox is bigger than the screen (There's just a Listbox, no other elements. ListBox should have full height then), then I can't even see more items... Anyway, gonna try it out (later), else I'll just define a MaxLength for the Text.

Comment: tried it, still the same problem...